# Vite: How to replace vue.config.ts devServer option in vite.config.ts

Tags: vite

I moved to vite and wish to migrate the devServer option from vue.config.ts to vite.config.ts, but am unsure how to do so.

**vue.config.ts**

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '^/example/': {
                target: 'http://php:80',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to `vue.config.js`, create (if not exiting already) `vite.config.js` at the project's root directory and have the following element added

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:3000',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Change the port number to your actual node server's port. `'/'` will forward every request to Node server, so you may want to use a RegExp or a prefix to forward only selected requests to Node and rest/non-matching to be served by vite fron-end dev server.

More in vite documentation here https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy